# How to remove noise from frequency spectrum?

Tags: filters, noise

I have a signal acquired at 40 MHz sampling rate, from an ultrasound transducer with center frequency of 5 MHz.

The frequency spectrum is shown in attached images (whole spectrum and zoomed).

There is ~400 KHz noise present in the whole spectrum (see red boxes).

How can I filter this noise? It looks like a abs(sinc) multiplied in frequency domain :/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not a bandpass filter?

Comment: The boxes are examples, but the oscillations are present on all the spectrum. Maybe I am missing something how a bandpass can remove the oscillation over the whole spectrum?

Comment: When applying a low pass filter to the measured frequency spectrum (n.b. in the frequency domain, not in the time domain), make sure you use a non-causal low pass filter.